# for loop recursion with a n-ary tree node

Tags: java, function, recursion, tree

The recursive function call abruptly stucks after reaching a limit.

when the function is called from main, the root node is passed first, and in a loop the children of root node is checked for the size's value and recursively the same function is called on that child to sets its size value.

my input is very big tree. when i print the n-ary tree before setting the size for the elements in the tree, the list is getting printed with all the elements. but, during the setsize() recursion, the execution hangs at a particular point un-meaningfully. everytime the execution stops at the same element. if i remove the elements after that element where it hangs from my input while creating the n-ary tree, the execution is successful and does not hangs.

i tried increasing -Xss -Xmx -Xss. still no use.

do i got to use threading or pls let me know if any issues in my below recursive method for the above explained function implementation. Thx!!

```
public void setsize(Element inEle){
        for(int i =0;i<inEle.children.size();i++){
            if(inEle.children.get(i).size==0)
            {                   
                this.setsize(inEle.children.get(i));
                i--;
            }else
            {
                if(!inEle.children.get(i).isRedefine)
                    inEle.size=inEle.size+inEle.children.get(i).size;                   
            }
        }
        inEle.size=inEle.size*inEle.occurs;
    }
```

Comment: What is the `size` of an Element supposed to represent? The number of elements below it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that something wrong with `i++` and `i--` in the same condition.

Note: recursive call save state of your local variables, so don't try it by yourself.

Comment: The `i--` looks like it's doing that so that it can run that iteration of the loop again so it can accurately process the child.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this line, `inEle.size=inEle.size+inEle.children.get(i).size;` it looks like the size of an Element is the sum of the sizes below it. The problem I see is that there's never any place for it to start. So, let's just assume it's counting the nodes, and then you could change the actual calculation to whatever you wanted.

The first thing I would do is change the `setSize` method to also return the size as well as set. So as follows

```
public int setSize(Element parent) {
    int size = 0;
    for(Element child : parent.children()) { // enhanced for loop
        size += setSize(child);
    }
    parent.size = size + 1; // the +1 is the current node
    return size;
}
```

Then you can just call it on the root:

```
int treeSize = setSize(root);
```